# Can I create file on google drive using GoogleIdToken on server side?

Tags: spring-boot, google-drive-api, google-signin

our clients have authorised on website using firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider with drive scope.
I have sent the credential, accessToken, idToken to server side(JAVA).
this is the code on

my app.js

```
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(googleAuthProvider).then(function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            $scope.authOnServerSide(result.credential);
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

I have followed "Authenticate with a backend server" tutorial, using GoogleIdTokenVerifier on server side and got GoogleIdToken object.

this is the code on my spring boot application

```
GoogleIdTokenVerifier verifier = new GoogleIdTokenVerifier.Builder(transport, jsonFactory)
              .setAudience(Collections.singletonList(googleAuthClientId))
               .build();
        GoogleIdToken googleIdToken = verifier.verify(googleAuthorizationDTO.getIdToken());
```

My question is, how to use this GoogleIdToken/accessToken to make operations such as create file on that user's google drive, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

```
            GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential();
            credential.setAccessToken(googleAuthEntity.getAccessToken());

            Drive drive = new Drive.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), credential).build();
```